# Emulator hangs after running the android program

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am trying to run application on android emulator. The application showing list-view with images. When i am trying to run the application it launches well on emulator without any warning or error if i keep emulator idle for 1-2min it gets hang. It stop responding completely. Evert time i need to start it manually then i can run application again.

I am not getting where i am getting wrong, why my emulator gets hang.

And i am facing one more problem i set minSdkVersion="8" and targetSdkVersion="16" but when i run it on below API level 16 emulators the application appears in black and white color.

Can any one guide me for this.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

First question:

Try creating a new emulator, try restarting eclipse, lastly try updating all of your ADT and SDK. Lastly, try turning your computer off and on again.

Second question:

Set a theme in your manifest. If you don't set a theme it will default to the API level default. The holo theme was introduced in Honeycomb, so everything below honeycomb will usually look a lot different.

Comment: thanks @EGHDk for replying. I solved the 2nd issue. But for 1st still its hangs after updating, deleting and recreating emulator.

Comment: Hmm... did you try updating all of your ADT, SDK, and updating eclipse to Eclipse Juno?

Comment: I solved the 1st issue without upadating the eclipse. I remove the style parameter from manifest and create a new xml file in drawable foldewr and assign that file whwnver i want. Now it showing the same UI on all platforms without hanging the emulator